# How can I get a messaging menu indicator with unread count of my new Gmail emails?

Tags: software-recommendation, 13.04, notification, gmail, system-tray

Back in Ubuntu 12.04, installing the `gm-notify` application allowed did these things:

- Shoe me the number of unread messages in my inbox
- Show me a blue envelope when an email was received
- Show me a notification when an email was received

[image]

I have done a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.04 and installed and configured gm-notify, and it only shows me a notification.  The messaging menu no longer has an inbox count and no longer turns blue.

What can I do to restore the old behavior and get blue icons as well as an inbox count in the system tray?

If there's a bug in gm-notify or in Ubuntu 13.04, is there an alternative to accomplish this?

Please note - I am aware of the Gmail Unity Webapp but that requires the browser to remain open and is overall too problematic, and I would like to find out how to restore the blue envelope + message count functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of mail-notifiers (Popper, GmailWatcher, Gmail-Notify) stopped working from 12.10 because of change in messaging-menu api. You can always file a bug on their respective launchpad page.

However there are few which works with new api ( Unity-Mail, Thunderbird, Evolution).

### [Unity Mail](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-mail) [image: Install unity-mail]

**Launchpad:** https://launchpad.net/unity-mail

With Unity Mail we can handle multiple gmail accounts. You will get an OSD notification whenever you receive a new mail showing the sender, and the subject of a mail.

[image]

In addition it adds a launcher icon to display the count of unread messages, integrates with the mail indicator to turn it blue, and displays a list of mails in the drop down menu there.

[image]

**PPA:** [ppa:mitya57/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Emitya57/+archive/ppa)

[image: Install via the software center]

---

Source: [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/posts/293923/edit)

Comment: I had tried Unity Mail before this but didn't realize that it was actually changing the envelope color - to a light gray, not blue as I expected.  But your answer is right, I should have noticed.  I don't suppose you know where I could change that color?  

Popper did not seem to work at all, it doesn't check or notify even.

Comment: I must wait 19 hours to award a bounty.

Comment: OK - icon question answered as well.  I had to change the indicator-messages-new.png icon in /usr/share/icons under my theme, under status/22.  I must still wait 19 hours to award a bounty. :D

Comment: Popper didn't work? OK I will modify my answer to reflect that.Anyway, glad to know you fixed your icon-color problem before i could comment. As far as I know, Unity-mail does depend on gnome icon theme. I always used Awoken (more complete icon theme);may be that's why I didn't have any problem at all.