# How to remove status options from Messages Indicator?

Tags: unity, indicator, indicator-message

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 with Unity. 
I'm willing to have an *indicator* for my Gmail inbox.

---

- **My current situation :**

I now use `unity-mail`, which works great with `indicator-messages` and is fully integrated in Unity. But I have one thing that I don't like, check this screenshot :

[image: indicator-messages with unity-mail]

As you can see, `indicator-messages` still shows me status *"available", "away", "invisible"*, and such. I would like to only have my emails, I don't care about the other things this package can do.

---

- **A way to achieve this** :

I saw [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291162/how-can-i-get-a-messaging-menu-indicator-with-unread-count-of-my-new-gmail-email) this screenshot : this is exaclty what I would like to have !

[image: indicator-messages status-free]

I also saw [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185021/how-to-remove-or-hide-chat-status-icons-from-messaging-menu) that I could use the sources to recompile `indicator-messages`, by modifying some lines. Unfortunately, the sources seems to have been rewritten, I can't follow the answer given, one file doesn't exist anymore and the code in the second file isn't the same.

---

- **So, here's the question :**

How can I recompile `indicator-messages` to hide the *status* on 13.10 ?

Comment: @Seth : it is indeed a duplicate, but if you had read my question, you would have seen that this link is outdated and the answer provided there can't be applied on 13.10

Comment: @Braiam : Shall I copy the answer provided by sneetcher to [12.04 question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185021/how-to-remove-or-hide-chat-status-icons-from-messaging-menu) and close this thread ?